# CSS transform RotateY() not working with animation?

Tags: html, css, xslt

I have a div with class called imgData. It has some background image applied to it. When mouse is not hovering on this div then there is a animation applied called clickMe. Which basically scales it. And when the mouse is on the div then it supposed to pause the animation and rotateY(360) and display another image. Everything is working but the rotationY() is not working. The rotationY() works if I remove animation only. Why is that? How to fix it? Here my code.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"  href="#style1"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
 id ID #IMPLIED>
]>
<doc>
  <head>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" id="style1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html> 
            <head>
                <style>
                    .imgData {
                        background: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-100-7.jpg");
                        background-size: 400px 180px;
                        height: 180px;
                        width:400px;
                        -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
                        -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
                        -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
                        -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
                        transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
                        animation-name: clickMe;
                        animation-duration: 1s;
                        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                        animation-direction: alternate;
                    }
                    .imgData:hover{     
                        animation-play-state: pause;
                        -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
                        -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
                        -o-animation-play-state: paused;
                        background: url("https://imgsnap.com/images/2015/10/14/6984999-cool-lights.jpg");
                        background-size: 400px 180px;
                        height: 180px;
                        width:400px;
                        cursor : pointer;
                        -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
                        -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
                        -o-transform: rotateY(360deg);
                        -ms-transform: rotateY(360deg);
                        transform: rotateY(360deg);
                    }

                    @keyframes clickMe {
                        from {transform: scale(1,1);}
                        to {transform: scale(1.1,1.1);}
                    }

                    @-webkit-keyframes clickMe {
                        from {transform: scale(1,1);}
                        to {transform: scale(1.1,1.1);}
                    }

                    @-moz-keyframes clickMe {
                        from {transform: scale(1,1);}
                        to {transform: scale(1.1,1.1);}
                    }

                    @-o-keyframes clickMe {
                        from {transform: scale(1,1);}
                        to {transform: scale(1.1,1.1);}
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body><div class="imgData"></div></body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</head>
<body><imageURL></imageURL></body>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I something like this expected? Run the snippet.

```css
.imgData {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-100-7.jpg");
    background-size: 400px 180px;
    height: 180px;
    width:400px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    animation-name: clickMe;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
.imgData:hover{     
    background-size: 400px 180px;
    height: 180px;
    width:400px;
    background: url("https://imgsnap.com/images/2015/10/14/6984999-cool-lights.jpg");
    cursor : pointer;
    animation: rotate 2s normal forwards ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotateY(0deg) }
  100% { transform: rotateY(360deg) }
}

@keyframes clickMe {
    from {transform: scale(1,1);}
    to {transform: scale(1.1,1.1);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes clickMe {
    from {transform: scale(1,1);}
    to {transform: scale(1.1,1.1);}
}

@-moz-keyframes clickMe {
    from {transform: scale(1,1);}
    to {transform: scale(1.1,1.1);}
}

@-o-keyframes clickMe {
    from {transform: scale(1,1);}
    to {transform: scale(1.1,1.1);}
}
```

```html
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"  href="#style1"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
 id ID #IMPLIED>
]>
<doc>
  <head>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" id="style1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html> 
            <head>
            </head>
            <body><div class="imgData"></div></body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</head>
<body><imageURL></imageURL></body>
</doc>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured will be the solution. You basically introduce another animation for rotate right? Thats what I thought. Anyway it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"  href="#style1"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
 id ID #IMPLIED>
<doc>
  <head>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" id="style1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html> 
            <head>
                <style>
                    .imgData {
                        background: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-100-7.jpg");
                        background-size: 400px 180px;
                        height: 180px;
                        width:400px;
                        -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
                        -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
                        -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
                        -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
                        transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
                        animation-name: clickMe;
                        animation-duration: 1s;
                        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                        animation-direction: alternate;
                    }
                    .imgData:hover{     
                        animation-play-state: pause;
                        -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
                        -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
                        -o-animation-play-state: paused;
                        background: url("https://imgsnap.com/images/2015/10/14/6984999-cool-lights.jpg");
                        background-size: 400px 180px;
                        height: 180px;
                        width:400px;
                        cursor : pointer;
                        -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
                        -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
                        -o-transform: rotateY(360deg);
                        -ms-transform: rotateY(360deg);
                        transform: rotateY(360deg);
                    }

                    @-ms-keyframes clickMe {
                        from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
                        to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
                    }
                    @-moz-keyframes clickMe {
                        from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
                        to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
                    }
                    @-webkit-keyframes clickMe {
                        from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
                        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
                    }
                    @keyframes clickMe {
                        from {
                            transform:rotate(0deg);
                        }
                        to {
                            transform:rotate(360deg);
                        }
                    }

                </style>
            </head>
            <body><div class="imgData"></div></body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</head>
<body><imageURL></imageURL></body>
</doc>
```

I think your css3 transform code error, I just change your CSS part and past it here please check this is you mean.